# Word list in file bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to do Unix script, witch print a list of uniq words form file and print list of numbers of rows where this word appearing.

For eample file.txt

```
Lorem 
ipsum dolor elit,
Lorem elit.
```

Output

```
Lorem 1,3
ipsum 2
dolor 2
elit 2,3
```

My code:

```
cat file.txt | tr '[:space:]' '[\n*]'| tr '[:digit:]' '[\n*]'| tr '[:punct:]' '[\n*]' | grep -v "^\s*$" | sort -f | uniq
```

I don't know how I can do it... Someone can help me?

Comment: have you already tried something to write and on a which step you stuck?

Comment: Yes:
cat file.txt | tr '[:space:]' '[\n*]'| tr '[:digit:]' '[\n*]'| tr '[:punct:]' '[\n*]' | grep -v "^\s*$" | sort -f | uniq

Comment: Complete your first post with this piece of code and explain that you didn't succeed to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

This awk codes works for your example:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        gsub(/[.,:;]/,"",$i)
        a[$i]=($i in a)?a[$i]","NR:NR}}
     END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' file
```

Comment: @dawg I do think about the `[:punct:]` but it contains `-` or `_`, I don't think it should be removed when we do word count calculation.

Answer (score 1):

some write-only perl:

```
perl -nE '
    push @{$refs{$_}}, $. for /(\w+)/g
  } END { 
    say $_, "\t", join(",", @{$refs{$_}}) for keys %refs
' file
```

```
elit    2,3
Lorem   1,3
ipsum   2
dolor   2
```

It does not output the order of words as "when they when they were encountered in the file": the order is unspecified.

Also, if a word appears twice on one line, the line number will be added twice. To improve this:

```
perl -MList::Util=uniq -nE '
    push @{$refs{$_}}, $. for uniq /(\w+)/g
  } END { 
    say $_, "\t", join(",", @{$refs{$_}}) for keys %refs
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care that the words are in a different order than encountered in the file:

```
awk -F[^[:alpha:]] '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) 
                       if ($i) a[$i]=a[$i]?a[$i] "," NR:NR} 
                 END {for (e in a) print e,a[e]}' file
```

Or, if you want in the order encountered in the file:

```
awk -F[^[:alpha:]] 'FNR==NR{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) 
                       if ($i) a[$i]=a[$i]?a[$i] "," NR:NR
                    next}
                    {for (i=1; i<=NF;i++){
                           if ($i in seen) continue 
                           else if ($i) {
                                   print $i,a[$i]
                                   seen[$i] } }
                     }' file file
```